# SQL: Using a subquery to compare Averages

Tags: sql

I've been trying to set up this query.

```
SELECT P.ProductNo,P.Description, AVG(OrderLine.ActualPrice)
FROM Product P
INNER JOIN OrderLine
     ON OrderLine.ProductNo = P.ProductNo
WHERE AVG(ActualPrice) > 
                 (SELECT AVG(ActualPrice)
                          FROM OrderLine)
```

My goal here is to compare the average actual price for a product to the average price of all products together. But I don't seem to be getting it to work. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Show us the tables structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- use `GROUP BY`
- when using aggregated condition, use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`

query,

```
SELECT  P.ProductNo, P.Description, AVG(OrderLine.ActualPrice)
FROM    Product P
        INNER JOIN OrderLine
              ON OrderLine.ProductNo = P.ProductNo
GROUP BY P.ProductNo, P.Description
HAVING AVG(ActualPrice) > (SELECT AVG(ActualPrice)  FROM OrderLine)
```

Comment: Okay, so use HAVING when using aggregated conditions over WHERE, and GROUP BY to get them in order. Thank you again for your assistance John! Pretty sure I've learned more about SQL browsing around here than  I have in my design classes :D.

Comment: `GROUP BY` doesn't order, it categorized the rows. in this case by `ProductNo` and `Description`

Comment: actually, HAVING acts on the GROUP BY clause, not the WHERE clause.